# Notification permission gives denied always

Tags: javascript, angularjs, notifications

I'm using `Notification.permission` to check whether the browser allows notifications or not.
Here is how I check for `Notification.permission` in my code:

```js
// Let's check if the browser supports notifications
if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
}
var prm = Notification.permission;
if (prm == 'default' || prm == 'denied') {
    console.log("permission denied or default");
} else {
    console.log("permission granted");
}
```

This code is working fine on my `localhost`, but when I try to use it in production, it always returns a '**denied**' status. My browser settings for notifications are set to '**always allow on this site**'.
[image: my browser settings]
I'm currently unable to identify the issue.

Comment: `it will always give denied status` - your code treats "denied" and "default" as the same thing, are you sure you're denied?

Comment: yes, if prm == 'default' || prm == 'denied' i want to print console.log("permission denied or default"); but prm gives always denied status in production but perfectly works in localhost.

Comment: your notification settings is `Ask (default)` according to the image - though you claim "my browser settings for notification is **always allows on this site.**"

Comment: oh, sorry image comes wrong . I updated image.

Comment: the same thing happened to me, By default chrome blocks all notifications if site is not secure

Comment: yes @HimanshuBansal if the site is not secure then it always gives denied. I tested in https then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 12):

That's easy it says:
`[Deprecation]` The Notification API may no longer be used from insecure origins. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as `HTTPS`. See [google's advice](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) for more details.
(anonymous) @ ?message=unique-identifier=123:25
?message=unique-identifier=123:26 denied
you lint should look smth like this:
`[linkExample1][2]` - for index.html or `[linkExampe2][2]`

---

[Here is the link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrrmaO) *it will not work online* **but you can run it on local server** just create any html(htm) file and **run it in `HTTPS` protocol then select `Allow` option in your URL:**
[image: Hear is what i mean]

> One small **gotcha** do not use *private*(*incognito mode*) for this lab - for
>   **security reason** **push notifications are not supported** in *private* or
>   *incognito mode*

```js
    let dnperm = document.getElementById('dnperm');
    let dntrigger = document.getElementById('dntrigger');

    dnperm.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if(!window.Notification){
            alert("Notification not supported!");
        }else{
            Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
                console.log(permission);
                if(permission === 'denied'){
                    alert('You Have Denied Notification!');
                }else if(permission === 'granted'){
                    alert('You Have Granted notification.');
                }
            })
        }
    });

    // simulate

    dntrigger.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        let notify;

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(Notification.permission);

        if(Notification.permission === 'default'){
            alert('Please allow notification before doing this');
        }else {
            notify = new Notification('New Message From Romzik', {
                body: 'How are you today? Is it really is a lovely day.',
                icon: 'img/msg-icon.png',
                tag: 'unique-identifier=123' // msg-id
            });

            notify.onclick = function (ev) {
                console.log(this);
                window.location = '?message=' + this.tag;
            }
        }


    })
```

```html
<body>
<a href="" id="dnperm">Request permission</a>
<a href="" id="dntrigger">Trigger</a>
</body>
```