# Notification.permission always return 'denied' on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, notifications

I have a problem with Push notifications only on Firefox.
It always return 'denied' when I am checking the permissions, even though they are granted and firefox shows me next to url tab that they are granted.

I have this problem on production (https). I was looking for an answer online, but every time people had this problem on localhost.
On chrome and safari it works fine.
Have you ran on that issue and have a solution ?

PS. For example on old Firefox 79 it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Might helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447637/notification-permission-gives-denied-always

Comment: Later versions of Firefox can only request permission in response to a user gesture such as a click event, how are you attempting to request permission? Please share any relevant code.

Comment: I open an iframe (B.com/check-notifications) and code of this iframe check Notification.permission to "B.com" and return to my page (A.com) if it has permissions.