# PWA - Notification Permissions Android

Tags: javascript, android, web, progressive-web-apps, onesignal

I'm building a PWA with push notifications (OneSignal). I've got everything working if permissions are set correctly. The problem is, if someone accepts notification permissions in the browser and then installs my PWA, Android automatically blocks notifications for my app. On the other hand, if you don't accept notification permissions in the browser but do it in the app, everything works fine, until someone deletes the app and reinstalls it.

The problem lies with the notification permissions set in the browser and being copied over to the standalone installed version. For as far as I know, Android 13 requires specific notification permission within the app before it can send notifications, which means the user would have to click another 'accept' button. But since permission is already granted in the browser, this pop-up won't show up, and users would have to manually enable notifications via device settings, which is very inconvenient.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this situation? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried resending the notification permission prompt when the user was on the stand alone installed version, but this won't work. (I came across another discussion on StackOverflow about resending prompts: [Resetting denied HTML notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133781/resetting-denied-html-notifications))